# Is it possible to boot backtrack from usb on a macbook pro?

Tags: mac, usb, bootable-disk

I would like to boot [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/) on my MacBook Pro from a USB drive but it seems impossible. I'm holding the Alt key on boot, but the mac only displays "Macintosh HD", i.e. it doesn't recognize my USB. Anybody knows if booting a Linux distro from a usb possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](https://superuser.com/a/58654) your USB stick, to be bootable, must be setup for [EFI](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)/GPT.

Comment: I tried it, but it gets stack when it tries to detect some stuff. It hangs very early in the beginning.